# Dell Inspiron 1520 Blue Screen of Death after Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

After installing Windows 7 on my Dell Inspiron 1520 laptop I am getting the blue screen of death quite often. Often it is when I am debugging or watching videos on FireFox browser. I am not sure if this has something to do with any FireFox plugin or maybe some video driver missing.

I am coming from Windows XP to Windows 7. Should I download and install the Windows Vista 32 bit drivers for display on my machine?

UPDATE:

I installed the blue screen view and right now less than (3) minutes ago I got another blue screen. The error is shown on the following link:

http://highoncoding.com/bluescreen.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Download bluescreen viewer:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Once the program is installed you will be able to see the windows dump files that are created after the bluescreen.

A guide to using the bluescreen viewer is here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6292/how-to-troubleshoot-the-blue-screen-of-death/

We used this tool a few days ago and once we found the driver file that was causing the blue screen, we went into the windows recovery console and replaced it with the default file off the windows CD.

Comment: Awesome! I will download and use it :)